# query out of multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have a website were people can like stuff, i need it so that when someone clicks a button they can see everyone who liked that post and the persons who liked it there followers and following count in a nice list.

when you click the button on the post i will get a variable containing the id of the post i then want to use that id to see where its equal to likes.post then it should get the likes.users from that row and get the users info from the user table (users.id) by that id and get that users follwering and followers count from the follow table also by the id(follow.user).

my first attempt to make a query to get this failed badly and i get a syntax error for" 'WHERE 1 = likes.post' at line 9  " but i think im not doing it right anyway and that there most be a better version, also performance is a big issue considering the trafic that will use this.

here is what i currently made but doesnt work:

```
$query = "SELECT likes.user, users.*,
   COUNT(follow.follower) AS Followers,
   COUNT(follow2.following) AS Followings
   from likes
   LEFT JOIN follow ON likes.user = follow.follower
   LEFT JOIN follow AS follow2 ON likes.user = follow.follower
   LEFT JOIN users ON likes.user = users.id
   GROUP BY likes 
   WHERE $liked = likes.post
   ";
```

if someone knows how to do it properly you would be a life saver sinds i cant get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

whats `$liked` here?

$liked get evaluated in PHP, and if its has no value, it results in an Syntax error as `WHERE = likes.post`

You should replace `$liked` by some specific column name of your table.

the `Where clause` is expecting a column name, not a numerical value. Whereas the value of `$liked` is 1.

**UPDATE**

change your code to

```
WHERE likes.post =  $liked
```

Comment: likes is the variable of the post, it contains the id of the post that should match likes.post where people have liked it.

Comment: what syntax error? same or different? also trying placing WHERE CLAUSE before GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building a query by concatenating strings, you should really use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  Some of the advantages are:

- security -- less open to SQL injection
- clarity -- easy to see what the parameters of the query are
- performance -- the db server may be able to cache the query, instead of recompiling it each time

Here are some of the issues with the original query:

- `group by` comes before `where`
- table alias `follow2` is created but never used
- non-`group by`, non-aggregated columns are selected

Comment: thanks this is helpfull but i would like to get the query to work first

Comment: I've added a list of problems with the original query.